# Remove specific character from compositor

Tags: keyboard, xorg, language-support, input-method

My keyboard settings are set to "US, alt. intl" and something that bothers me is that whenever I try to write words like "we've" I end up writing "weǘe" because '+v creates the "ǘ" character. If I try `+v it creates ǜ.

I don't use any of those characters in my writing, I would like to remove those from the compositor, that way I can properly write "we've" without writing "weǘe" every time.

I've already tried to edit the X11 file in `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`, but it didn't change anything.

Appreciate any guidance here :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm on Ubuntu 23.04, using Xorg because Wayland doesn't work really well with my Nvidia

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as the basic *English (US)* keyboard layout would fit your needs better. If you need to type accented letter occasionally you may want to combine that layout with the use of a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose).

Another option is the *English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)* layout. It only starts composition involving dead keys if you ask it to by pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd>/<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>.

' followed by v -> 'v

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+' followed by v -> ǜ

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
The first option don't really fit because I do use a lot of the compose, as I'm native Portuguese speaker I use a lot of ç, á and é. Changing how I use those other would likely hurt a lot my typing.

About the second option, I still can write 'weǘe' even that I'm using US into, with AltGr dead keys

Comment: @euDennis: I see. With the *English (US, intl., with dead keys)* layout: Maybe you can just make it a habit to press ' twice when typing we've.

Comment: I found making a '+<space> being easier, but yes. There is workarounds, is just not optimal, but is fine. Thanks for the help